# How to capture thread dump programatically using JAVA Code?

Tags: java, multithreading, mxbean

I want to generate thread dump through java code, I tried using ThreadMXBean for this but I am not getting the thread dump in the proper format as we are getting using **jstack** command. Please can any one provide some help..is their any other way to get thread dump... using any other API.. The format of thread dump that i want is -

```
2015-08-06 05:51:15
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fdab805d800 nid=0x7a36 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]


java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"ajp-mco/127.168.121.120:8170-220" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fdaa056d000 nid=0x7961 runnable [0x00007fda8bb7a000]


java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:1114)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.readMessage(AjpProcessor.java:1196)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: I believe `jstack` itself uses `ThreadMXBean` to get this information. Admittedly, this is different from the thread dump that one gets on sending `kill -3` to the process.

Comment: yeah but when I am using ThreadMXBean I am not getting complete information like tid, nid, thread is daemon or not... these information I am not able to get through threadMXBean.

Comment: unfortunately, i don't think java exposes a way to get those additional details.

Answer (score 15):

Try `ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().dumpAllThreads(true, true)` using something like

```
ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
ThreadInfo[] infos = bean.dumpAllThreads(true, true);
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(infos).map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Alternatively you can hack your way around and actually call `jstack` through `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`:

```
String pid = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
InputStream in = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PATH_TO_JSTACK + " " + pid).getInputStream();
System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(InputStream));
```

Here's the output for a sample program using

`ThreadMXBean`:

```
"pool-1-thread-4" Id=14 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d98a335
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d98a335
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-3" Id=13 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d98a335
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d98a335
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-2" Id=12 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d98a335
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d98a335
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-1" Id=11 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d98a335
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d98a335
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" Id=10 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    -  locked java.net.SocksSocketImpl@16b98e56
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain$1.run(AppMain.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Attach Listener" Id=5 RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" Id=4 RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" Id=3 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@7ef20235
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@7ef20235
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" Id=2 WAITING on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@27d6c5e0
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@27d6c5e0
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)

"main" Id=1 RUNNABLE
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:446)
    at Playground.main(Playground.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

`jstack` (thorugh the console or through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`):

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" #15 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000008bd800 nid=0x41c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"pool-1-thread-4" #14 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000016660800 nid=0x166c waiting on condition [0x0000000016dff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eb360088> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-3" #13 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000016660000 nid=0x1e34 waiting on condition [0x0000000016cff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eb360088> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-2" #12 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001665f000 nid=0x148 waiting on condition [0x0000000016bff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eb360088> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-1" #11 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001665b800 nid=0xdf0 waiting on condition [0x0000000016afe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eb360088> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001641d000 nid=0x2038 runnable [0x00000000169fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
        - locked <0x00000000eb39db18> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain$1.run(AppMain.java:90)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000014a1e000 nid=0x360 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000149c3800 nid=0x89c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000149c0800 nid=0x2048 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000149bd800 nid=0x1aa0 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000149bc000 nid=0x108c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000149bb000 nid=0x15a4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x00000000023b1000 nid=0x182c in Object.wait() [0x0000000015d1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000eb2070b8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
        - locked <0x00000000eb2070b8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000023ae000 nid=0x21f4 in Object.wait() [0x0000000015c1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000eb206af8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
        - locked <0x00000000eb206af8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000014987000 nid=0x17cc runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000022d7800 nid=0x2208 runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000022d9000 nid=0x24c4 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000022da800 nid=0x7b0 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000022dc000 nid=0x2650 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001634a800 nid=0x271c waiting on condition

JNI global references: 321
```

Comment: I want the exact same thread dump to be generated from java code as we are getting from Jstack, so that we can analyse the dump using Thread dump Analyser, without any modifications...is it possible??

Comment: If you are fine with the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` hack, it will do that for you. Otherwise the only thing you cannot get is the native ID.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Thread.getAllStackTraces()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces--) to get most of this.

```
for (Map.Entry<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> entry : Thread.getAllStackTraces().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getKey().getState());
    for (StackTraceElement ste : entry.getValue()) {
         System.out.println("\tat " + ste);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Using this also not getting complete information like tid, nid, thread is daemon or not...

Comment: @RishiArora The key in the `Map` is the `Thread` object. It exposes these things. What is a `nid`?

Comment: @RishiArora I am not sure what a `tid` is or what it is used for, The nid` is the process id in hexidecimal.  You can get that using JNA but I not sure you need it. You can get `Thread.isDaemon()`